# LDAP: Retrieve entries from multiple OUs in one query

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

try to retrieve entries of objectClass 'groupOfNames' from multiple OUs from LDAP. My scheme looks like this:

```
ou=gp,ou=gruppen,dc=some,dc=my-company,dc=at
|
|-ou=99 (objectClass=organizaionalUnit)
   |-cn=admins (objectClass=groupOfNames)
   |-cn=managers (objectClass=groupOfNames)
|-ou=103 (objectClass=organizaionalUnit)
   |-cn=admins (objectClass=groupOfNames)
   |-cn=managers (objectClass=groupOfNames)
|-many more OUs
...
```

Now i try to create a query with which i can retrieve the admins/managers of the different OUs with one query. Within the CN the admins and managers groups contain the names of users that belong to theses groups. One filter i came up with was:

```
(cn=admins)
```

This Results in giving me back all the CNs of all OUs:

[image]

The search scope is set to complete subtree. How can I change this filter to get only the entries from specific OUs, e.g. ou=212917 and ou=211208, but not from the other OUs? The groups i want to extract in the end look like this:

[image: exampleOfGroupOfNames]

Or is there another possibility to realise this? I'm fairly new to LDAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use a very specific filter to search for only the groups with `cn=admins` in specific `OUs`.

`(&(cn=admins)(|(ou:dn:=212917)(ou:dn:=211208)))`

The notation means search for `ou=212917` in the entry or part of the DN. Not all servers support this though, even it's part of LDAPv3 standard specifications.